# Parsing a number of pixels to an integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code i'm trying to compare the height with the position of an element, to ensure that the element doesn't leave the game's div.

First I get the position of my element, snake. and if the cursor is too close then i move it.  Then at the end I do a check that it is at least 20 pixels away from the top and bottom.  For some reason everything is working except the when it reaches the bottom of the screen (which is the else if statement in the end block of code)

```
var posL = $("#snake").position().left;
var posT = $("#snake").position().top;
if((e.pageX-200 < posL) && (posL < e.pageX-50)){
  if(posL > 20){
    posL = posL - 5;
  }else{
    posT = posT + 5;
  }
```

...

```
if(posT < 20){
  posT = 20;
}else if(posT > parseInt($("#game").height)){
  posT = parseInt($("#game").height) - 20;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? If you're trying to detect collision at the very bottom of #game, you'll need to add the #snake height to posT.

Comment: my image is small enough so that i dont mind that being slightly off, what my problem was that the else if statement wasnt stopping it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `()` after `.height` ...twice! ;-)

```
if(posT < 20) {
   posT = 20;  // ------------------------v
} else if(posT > parseInt($("#game").height)){
   posT = parseInt($("#game").height) - 20;
}              // -----------------^
```